# Routing in vue js 404 page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

guys so basically i have my routes.js file where obviously my routes are, but am trying to add another route which will redirect to a 404 page if a user tries to access routes that are not on my application

`{ path: '*', component: require('./components/NotFound.vue') }`

Heres my route.js file

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import profile from './components/Profile'
import user from './components/Users'
import unauthorized from './components/Unauthorized'

/**
 *
 *
     better run npm run watch or your routes will not work
     also the main page is the one with the id="app"
     dont forget to add a link in that main page to app.js
     <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
 *
 *
 */

let routes = [
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            component: dashboard
        },
        {
            path: '/profile',
            component: profile
        },
        {
            path: '/users',
            component: user
        },
        {
            path: '/unauthorized',
            component: unauthorized,
            name: unauthorized
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            component: 404
        }


]






export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

thats is what i wrote and it gives me error and does not work, please in need of assistance

thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no `404` component imported.
Also don't name it `404`, name it `PageNotFound.vue`

Comment: bro, u just missed an entire import of a component

Comment: yes the import for the 404 page right , you mean this ``` import 404 from './components/404' , thats gives an error too

Comment: rename it into `PageNotFound` instead `404`. otherwise what does the error say?

Comment: yes it works but maybe your not understanding what am saying , when someone searches for and unknown url its should display the PageNotFound , how do i do that ?

Answer (score -1):

so i actually solved the error the solution was to

firstly include my vue file
 `import notfound from './components/Notfound'`
then add this to my path

```
{
            path: '*',
            component: notfound
        }
```

Comment: bro. that is exactly what i told you. `there is no 404 component imported` means that!